# How to hit SAP HANA rest APIs through postman?

Tags: rest, hana

I am trying to hit SAP HANA's rest APIs but unable to get started because i didn't get any proper document that specifies the steps that i can use to hit APIs through POSTMAN(or any other rest client). Do i need to install anything before using the resp APIs or are they available to be used directly? Also what all are the parameters that i need to mention while hitting the API and what is the base URL that is to be used?

Comment: Which APIs are you specifically after? What have you tried and what error did you get? Which HANA version are you using?

Comment: The API version is 2.1.1(SPS01). I am trying to hit http://<host>:<port>/sap/hana/xs/dt/base/info but getting error in postman as COULD NOT GET ANY RESPONSE. I am not sure if this is the correct way to call this. I didn't get any info on what should be used in place of <host>:<post> and what should be the instance URL and where can i find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the HANA XS API is documented: [SAP HANA XS JavaScript API Reference](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/3de842783af24336b6305a3c0223a369/1.0.12/en-US/index.html)

For the error: most likely, you're not using any authentication in Postman. When you e.g. switch to "Basic Auth" and key in your HANA username and password, something like this

`https://<hostname>:43<instance no>/sap/hana/xs/dt/base/info`

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample Request in to Hit REST API Using Postman :
1. http://localhost:8080/my-rest-api/progress-report?name=shekhar&region=east&address=India

2. Add Headers Info if any : like
   accept : application/json;v=1
   contentType : application/json;v=1